# How to verify downloaded file by checking the Network in devtools

Tags: javascript, file, networking, download, verify

I am writing an automated test for my company.

You have to press a button, and then a file gets downloaded DIRECTLY, so you won't be redirected to an url.

I now have to verify that the file is downloaded correctly. I will verify this by checking the network response.

Could somebody give me the code / advice/ page of how to check the network response? I want to verify the response that I get when I press download. I see the response in devtools /Network. I want to verify  particular file.

I am sorry if it is a noob question, I'm new into the testautomation world, but I  really like it till now :)

Thank you all so much!

Stackoverflow, found no answer

There is no code yet

Comment: how about [200 OK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)?

Comment: How do I verify that Response xxx has 200 OK ? I am sorry for the noob question, but I can't find the proper code to work with.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you checking the response in Network tab visually or by using some tool (automated)? If first thing is the case, then in Network tab you can see the list of files and status codes too https://pasteboard.co/I7n2bpv.png Clicking on every single file will give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you don't want to verify the contents of the file, you only want to verify that a file was downloaded and the download finished without an error.

Based on that assumption it still depends on what you are using to download the file.

If you are using xhr the answer is to simply add `if(xhr.status === 200){ /*validation complete*/}` to your `xhr.onload` handler. This simply checks if the status code is 200 ok.

If you are using jquery you can check the status code inside the `$.ajax` settings. There you can add `statusCode: { 200:function(){/*validation complete*/}}` inside the settings object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cy.request('URL').then((response) => {
    cy.expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
```

this helped for me !